# Finding Resources with PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver and URLClassloader in JARs

Tags: spring, classpath

I am trying to load all resources with a specific file-extension which are loaded dynamically at runtime using a URLClassloader.

Unfortunately the PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver return no Resources when I use the pattern `classpath*:/*.myextension`. When I specify a file with its complete name like `classpath*:/test.myextension` the resource gets loaded, so I think the Classloader is configured right.

```
URLClassloader classloader = new URLClassloader(jarURLs); // jarURLs look like "file:C:/Temp/test.jar"
Thread.getCurrentThread().setContextClassloader(classloader)
ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(classloader);
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:/*.myextension") // yields empty array
....
```

How can I do this? I have to load the jars dynamically and I dont know the resource-names in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Tech Trip mentioned in the comment to his answer, I had an error in my pattern. The [Spring-documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html) is also quiet clear about that (see Warning): **"classpath*:" when combined with Ant-style patterns will only work reliably with at least one root directory before the pattern starts...originates from a limitation in the JDK's ClassLoader.getResources()**

So I changed my pattern to

```
classpath*/model/*.myextension
```

Since the JARs are created from an xText-DSL I have to enforce a convention that the model-folder has to be used.

Comment: When deployed as a WAR in Tomcat this works fine, but not for Jetty and Glassfish. For the latter cases one must specify a root folder for the wildcard, otherwise only that jar files resources will be returned.

Answer (score 51):

Loading the files dynamically in Spring is simple, I'd change the approach to finding the files with extensions.

Try the following:

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader(); 
ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:/*.xml") ;
for (Resource resource: resources){
    logger.info(resource.getFilename());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but where is the difference to my approach beside not using a separate Classloader? I thought I have to use a URLClassloader in order to access the jar-contents. In this example isn't the Classloader unnecessary since it is the one currently in use?

Comment: If you want to access some file that is in a jar on the classpath the above example works fine. You have to be careful however as the resolver in spring will detect multiple files of the same names.

As an example, suppose you want to find all the text files in a jar inside a path of temp/. You would simply grab it as follows:

`Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath:temp/**/*.txt");`

Note the use of the ** because of the ant style pattern matching. 

Your approach may work fine and it might be an issue with your pattern.

Comment: You were right about the pattern (see my answer). The URLClassloader is necessary nevertheless.