# Get a .zip file as resource in .java class inside .jar file

Tags: java, spring, jar, inputstream, classloader

My project structure is

```
---/src/java/package/TestZip.java
---/src/resource/package/My-1.0.1.zip
```

I want to get ***My-1.0.1.zip*** as a resource inside my ***TestZip.java*** class.

I have used following ways :
Way 1 :

```
TestZip.class.getResourceAsStream("My-1.0.1.zip")
```

Way 2:

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(TestZip.class.getClassLoader());
resolver.getResources("My-1.0.1.zip");
```

(with import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;)

Once I build my ***JAR***, the structure becomes :

```
---/package/TestZip.java
---/package/My-1.0.1.zip
```

Now if I change the version of my ***ZIP*** file to ***My-1.0.2.zip***, I have to change my code which I dont want.

Is it possible to get the resource based on regular expression like **My-*.zip** ?

Or

Is it possible to all the **ZIP** files from package folder ?

Comment: Hey. Isn't https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html already giving away how to match such a pattern? As well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405167/finding-resources-with-pathmatchingresourcepatternresolver-and-urlclassloader-in

Comment: thanx. that helped me. The regex will be "classpath*:**/package/*.zip"