# Spring Batch how to read all json files from a folder and all its sub-folders using PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch MultiResourceItemReader in order to read multipule files. these files are located at a parent directory and it's sub-directories.

Already tried:

1. Read the files by my own customized code and create the Resource array manually.
2. Use PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver as can be seen in the code example ( inspired by this [Finding Resources with PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver and URLClassloader in JARs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405167/finding-resources-with-pathmatchingresourcepatternresolver-and-urlclassloader-in)

   ```
   @Bean
   public MultiResourceItemReader<List<SingleJsonRowInput>> 
   multiResourceItemReader() {
   PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver  patternResolver = new 
   PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
   Resource resources[] = null;;
   try {
       resources = 
       patternResolver.getResources("file:C:\\inputFolder\\**\\*.json");
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   MultiResourceItemReader<List<SingleJsonRowInput>> 
   multiResourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
   multiResourceItemReader.setResources(resources);
   multiResourceItemReader.setDelegate(new 
   ItemReaderForMulti(fileManager));
   return multiResourceItemReader;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following snippet:

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("file:/root/folder/**/*.json");
```

The `**/*` will return the files recursively from the `root/folder`. Then you pass the resources array to the `MultiResourceItemReader`.

Comment: The snippet in my answer is for a unix based OS (tested on mac os in my case), but the same approach should work on windows with `file:C:\\inputFolder\\**\\*.json`.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, i tried using "file:C:\\inputFolder\\**\\*.json" ,  "C:\\inputFolder\\**\\*.json" and other variations but it doesn't seems to work. any idea on how to get it to work on Windows ?

Comment: you need to escape the back slash with `\\` as in the snippet. Both `file:C:\\inputFolder\**\*.json` and `C:\\inputFolder\**\*.json` you tried won't work on windows because the `\` is not escaped. Have you tried `file:C:\\inputFolder\\**\\*.json` as in my comment?

Comment: Thanks for the information, i'm not sure i understand what do you mean by "escape the back slash" as they are all double backslash , iv'e edited the current MultiResourceItemReader, how should i change the following line in order to get it to work ?                                                                                               resources = patternResolver.getResources("file:C:\\inputFolder\\**\\*.json");

Comment: Oh really sorry I just realized my previous comment was horribly formatted by SO (typing [backtick][backslash][backtick] is not correctly rendered in SO) and blew up the whole comment! What I mean is that since the back slash is a special character, you need to escape it (with another back slash). Both `file:C:\\inputFolder\**\*.json` and `C:\\inputFolder\**\*.json` that you tried won't work on windows because the \ just after `inputFolder` is not escaped. Have you tried `patternResolver.getResources("file:C:\\inputFolder\\**\\*.json");` ?

Comment: Yes, i edited the original question with the current code, it doesn't have any single backslash, all backslashes are doubled - but still - not Json file is found. any idea on what is missing here ?

Comment: In that case (and after seeing your answer), the example in my answer should work on windows too. I should **not** have added my first comment on my answer (which actually took us in the wrong path). But at least, I'm glad to see you fixed your issue! If that's the case, please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, it is working well now, i accepted the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using windows backslashes - the solution is to use Unix\Linux like syntax:

**Didn't work:** 
resources = patternResolver.getResources("file:C:\\inputFolder\\**\\*.json");

**Works well:** 
resources = patternResolver.getResources("file:C:/inputFolder/**/*.json");